# attribute error in tkinter, I can't use my method linked to a button

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

I tried to link the button "calculate_button" to the method I created "calculate()" that should simply print "you've just clicked"
though an error is raised that says there's no attribute calculate
I really don't understand where exactly should be written the method calculate and how to properly link the button to the method

this is the error

```
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'calculate
line 2095, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
File "deathcalculatorapp.py", line 102, in <lambda>
command=lambda: controller.calculate())
```

and this is the code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import datetime

LARGE_FONT = ("VERDANA", 12)


#user's information manager(classes and method)

class person:
    def __init__(self, name, birthday, sex, age, diet, smoker, physical_activity_frequency):
    self.name = name
    self.birthday = birthday
    self.sex = sex
    self.age = age
    self.diet = diet
    self.smoker = smoker
    self.physical_activity_frequency = physical_activity_frequency

    def age():
    today = datetime.today()
    person.age = person.birthday - today.year
    return person.age






#main windows

class deathCalculatorapp(tk.Tk):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "age calculator app")

    container = tk.Frame(self)
    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.frames = {}
    for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
        page_name = F.__name__
        frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[page_name] = frame

        # put all of the pages in the same location;
        # the one on the top of the stacking order
        # will be the one that is visible.
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    self.show_frame("StartPage")

def show_frame(self, page_name):
    '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
    frame = self.frames[page_name]
    frame.tkraise()

def calculate():
        print("you've jsut clicked the button")


#all of the frames

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller


    label = ttk.Label(self, text="deathcalculatorapp", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.grid(column=1, row=0)

    first_label = ttk.Label(self, text = "insert your data")
    year_label = tk.Label(self, text="year", bg ="lightblue", padx=9)
    month_label = tk.Label(self, text= "month", bg = "lightblue", padx=3)
    day_label = tk.Label(self, text ="day", bg= "lightblue", padx=11)

    first_label.grid(column=1, row=3)
    year_label.grid(column=0, row =4)
    month_label.grid(column=0, row =5)
    day_label.grid(column=0, row = 6)

    year_entry = tk.Entry(self,text = "", bg = "lightblue")
    month_entry = tk.Entry(self, text = "", bg= "lightblue")
    day_entry = tk.Entry(self, text= "", bg = "lightblue")

    year_entry.grid(column=1,row=4)
    month_entry.grid(column=1, row= 5)
    day_entry.grid(column=1, row=6)

    sex = tk.IntVar()

    female= ttk.Radiobutton(self, text="female",variable= sex, value="female")
    male=ttk.Radiobutton(self, text="male", variable= sex, value="male")
    female.grid(column=2, row=4)
    male.grid(column=2, row=5)

    calculate_button= ttk.Button(self, text="calculate your lifespawn",
                                 command= lambda: controller.calculate())
    calculate_button.grid(column=1, row=7)
    button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
    button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
    button1.grid(column=0, row=0)
    button2.grid(column=0, row=1)

    image = Image.open(r"/"
                       r"Users/tommasomasaracchio/Documents/pythonfolder/kushina4.jpg")
    image.thumbnail((500,300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    Photo_label= ttk.Label(self, image=photo)
    Photo_label.image = photo
    Photo_label.grid(row= 2, column = 1)




class PageOne(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    label = ttk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.grid(column=0, row=0)
    button = ttk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                       command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
    button.grid(column=0, row=0)


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    label = ttk.Label(self, text="This is page 2", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.grid(column=0, row=0)
    button = ttk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                       command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
    button.grid(column=0, row=0)






if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = deathCalculatorapp()
    app.mainloop()
```

thank you very much for your help, I appreciate

Comment: Please correct your indentation t be the same as you have in your script, it might be relevant to this issue.

Comment: Hello there!
If my code helped solving your problem please upvote it / choose it as answer please.

Answer (score 0):

I've corrected indentation and added self as your calculate function parameter, it works now.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import datetime

LARGE_FONT = ("VERDANA", 12)


#user's information manager(classes and method)

class person:
    def __init__(self, name, birthday, sex, age, diet, smoker, physical_activity_frequency):
        self.name = name
        self.birthday = birthday
        self.sex = sex
        self.age = age
        self.diet = diet
        self.smoker = smoker
        self.physical_activity_frequency = physical_activity_frequency

    def age():
        today = datetime.today()
        person.age = person.birthday - today.year
        return person.age

#main windows

class deathCalculatorapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "age calculator app")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def calculate(self):
            print("you've jsut clicked the button")


    #all of the frames

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller


        label = ttk.Label(self, text="deathcalculatorapp", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(column=1, row=0)

        first_label = ttk.Label(self, text = "insert your data")
        year_label = tk.Label(self, text="year", bg ="lightblue", padx=9)
        month_label = tk.Label(self, text= "month", bg = "lightblue", padx=3)
        day_label = tk.Label(self, text ="day", bg= "lightblue", padx=11)

        first_label.grid(column=1, row=3)
        year_label.grid(column=0, row =4)
        month_label.grid(column=0, row =5)
        day_label.grid(column=0, row = 6)

        year_entry = tk.Entry(self,text = "", bg = "lightblue")
        month_entry = tk.Entry(self, text = "", bg= "lightblue")
        day_entry = tk.Entry(self, text= "", bg = "lightblue")

        year_entry.grid(column=1,row=4)
        month_entry.grid(column=1, row= 5)
        day_entry.grid(column=1, row=6)

        sex = tk.IntVar()

        female= ttk.Radiobutton(self, text="female",variable= sex, value="female")
        male=ttk.Radiobutton(self, text="male", variable= sex, value="male")
        female.grid(column=2, row=4)
        male.grid(column=2, row=5)

        calculate_button= ttk.Button(self, text="calculate your lifespawn",
                                     command= lambda: controller.calculate())
        calculate_button.grid(column=1, row=7)
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button1.grid(column=0, row=0)
        button2.grid(column=0, row=1)

        image = Image.open(r"/"
                           r"Users/tommasomasaracchio/Documents/pythonfolder/kushina4.jpg")
        image.thumbnail((500,300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

        Photo_label= ttk.Label(self, image=photo)
        Photo_label.image = photo
        Photo_label.grid(row= 2, column = 1)



class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(column=0, row=0)
        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.grid(column=0, row=0)


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="This is page 2", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(column=0, row=0)
        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.grid(column=0, row=0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = deathCalculatorapp()
    app.mainloop()
```